# Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance, I confuse subclass inherit Object class and it's superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

I guess that answer may be "a class is not explicitly inherit, will implicit inherit Object class". But i'm not sure, in [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html), ... they all said : all class object implicit inherit Object class.

Comment: The two statements you quoted are in complete agreement. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I'm only not sure :) I'm want to be verified :)

Answer (score 1):

A class always has a single direct super-class, but it can have multiple ancestor classes (if class `C` extends `B` and class `B` extends `A` and class `A` extends `Object`, `C` has a single direct super-class - `B` - and 2 indirect super-classes - `A` and `Object`). If you don't specify the super-class in your class definition, the direct super-class will be the `Object` class by default.

If you specify a direct super-class in your class definition, that class would be the only direct super-class of your class. `Object` will still be an ancestor of your class, but it won't be the direct super-class of it.

Comment: ok, thank, I'm only not sure my anwer, Now it is more obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What they are trying to say is this:

This declaration:

```
class Foo
{
    ...         
}
```

Is the same as this one:

```
class Foo extends Object
{
    ...         
}
```